# Angular - How to map a nested JSON response to Angular models?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've been playing with Angular and hit a roadblock with nested JSON.

This demo app is for a sales catalog. Each `Catalog` will contain an array of `CatalogItemCategory` and each category will have an array of `CatalogItem`. All of these are `$resource` objects.

The backend responds with a nested JSON response (listed below).
Is there an 'angular-way' of mapping this to the client side?

Ideally I would prefer to keep the client side model as,

```
$scope.catalog = {};
$scope.catalog.catalogItemCategories = [];
$scope.catalog.catalogItemCategories[categoryIndex].catalogItems = [];
```

I've spent few hours on this, and the two solutions I can think of are,

1. Manually process the JSON response and build the nested model tree. OR
2. Fetch the root model ('catalog') first, build the nested tree, and then query the data for nested objects individually.

Obviously, the first approach will need a lot of maintenance work for a large JSON response, and the second will need many JSON calls. Is there an optimal way to do this?

```
{
id:1,
tenant_id:2,
business_id:1,
catalog_group_id:1,
name:"Catalog 1",
deleted_at:null,
created_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05",
updated_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05",
catalog_item_categories:[
    {
        id:3,
        tenant_id:2,
        business_id:1,
        catalog_id:1,
        name:"Services category 2",
        deleted_at:null,
        created_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05",
        updated_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05",
        catalog_items:[
        {
            id:3,
            tenant_id:2,
            business_id:2,
            catalog_item_category_id:3,
            quantity:null,
            price:"0.00",
            price_option:null,
            name:"CatalogItem 3",
            deleted_at:null,
            created_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05",
            updated_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05"
        },
        {
            id:4,
            tenant_id:2,
            business_id:2,
            catalog_item_category_id:3,
            quantity:null,
            price:"0.00",
            price_option:null,
            name:"CatalogItem 4",
            deleted_at:null,
            created_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05",
            updated_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     id:4,
     tenant_id:2,
     business_id:1,
     catalog_id:1,
     name:"Products categorys 2",
     deleted_at:null,
     created_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05",
     updated_at:"2014-06-14 12:34:05",
     catalog_items:[
     ]
  }
]
}
```

**EDIT**

After a couple of more hours, I got a solution. The idea is to pass the list of models as an array, then dynamically build the right model, based on the tree level in JSON. Obvious drawback is if the nesting levels of JSON changes, this won't work.

Posting my test solution below.

```
    function processObject(data, currentLevel, modelList) {

        var customResponse = {};
        angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
            if (angular.isArray(value)) {
                var arrayName = stringToCamelCase(key);
                var nextLevel = currentLevel + 1;
                var parsedArray = processArray(value, nextLevel, modelList);
                if (parsedArray.length) {
                    customResponse[arrayName] = parsedArray;
                }
            } else {
                customResponse[key] = value;
            }
        });

        var newobject = new modelList[currentLevel](customResponse);
        return newobject;

    }

    function processArray(data, currentLevel, modelList){

        var customResponse = [];
        angular.forEach(data, function(value) {

            customResponse.push(processObject(value, currentLevel, modelList));
        });
        return customResponse;

    }


    demoApp.controller('CatalogIndexController', function($scope, $http, BusinessService, $routeParams, Catalog, CatalogItemCategory, CatalogItem) {

        // setup defaults
        $scope.catalog = {};


        // load default catalog data
        $http.get('/business/' + $routeParams.businessId + '/catalogs/default')
            .success(function(data) {
                // 3rd argument - pass the nest structure as an array
                $scope.catalog = processObject(data, 0, [Catalog, CatalogItemCategory, CatalogItem]);
                console.log($scope.catalog);
            });

        $scope.save = function(item) {
            item.$save();
        };

    });
```

Comment: JSON stands for "JavaScript Object Notation". The response payload you have can be set directly without doing anything else. `$scope.catalog = theJsonPayload`. Is there any thing else you are looking for more than this?

Comment: I see the only difference is that the json uses `_` notation for object keys, but your model is camelCased. In that case you can either  traverse the json programatically and convert those keys to camelCase and use it directly or just use the json as is expecting model names to be using `_`.

Comment: I've tried `$scope.catalog = jsonData`. It works if I just want to show items. But the models are `$resource` objects, which comes with `$save()` and other REST methods. I've added the solution I've comeup with above. By doing this, I can directly call `update`, `delete` directly on the models. I thought there might be a built-in function in Angular, without having to traverse JSON.